# SQL Select max não ta funcionando bem

Tags: sql

Tenho esse código mas não ta funcionando bem não sei porque:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
SELECT email, MAX(a4cor) as a4c, MAX(a4preto) as a4p, MAX(a3cor) as a3c, MAX(a3preto) as a3p, MAX(totalcopias) as total FROM dados GROUP BY email
```

Não sei porque não está somando corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O 14166@espamol.pt era suposto mostrar 25 30 20 40 115

Comment: pq 25? pelo seu exemplo o max de a4cor que vejo é 20!
não está confundindo max com sum?

Comment: eu tava confundindo o código era sum em vez de max

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O `MAX()` pega o valor maior. Se vc quiser a soma, deve usar o `SUM()`

Comment: Era isso mas ontem eu tinha assim e tava funcionando estranho mas obrigado

Comment: deveria funcionar pq só tinha um valor e por acaso era o máximo :)

Comment: Por que minha resposta recebeu -1? Fiz algo errado?